Increasing all numeric values when clicking and dragging a cell down a column of cells (Excel 2010)
I am trying to come up with a formula within a cell that will increase two numeric values within a text string. So, when I click and drag that cell down a column of cells I will get the following:
A#3/Bb3
A#4/Bb4
A#5/Bb5
A#6/Bb6
A#7/Bb7
What I get when I click and drag cell A1 down the column is this:
A#3/Bb3
A#3/Bb4
A#3/Bb5
A#3/Bb6
A#3/Bb7
Note that the numeric value to the right of A#3 stays the same. But the numeric value to the right of Bb increases. How can I get them to both increase the same.
I have researched this site but have not found anything that works. Yesterday I spent 2 1/2 hour with an AI bot and even "it" could not come up with a solution.
Sure would appreciate anyone's help/suggestions
Thanks!

Type in =ROWS($A$1:A1) in A1, then "fill down" and you will se an increasing number.
For columns, use COLUMNS() in the same manner.
These can be used in formulas that do single, multi-stepping, sine, cosine and whatnot by adopting very simple addition or multiplication on the rows or columns count(s).
If you wish for more than one number to increase (change value), you need to use the same or similar formula at that position.
=ROWS($A$1:A1) & " - " & ROWS($A$1:A1)+2 will show a - b values in each cell (row), where b always is two steps larger.
